# Thank you message after the confirm purchase in virtuemart with authorize.net payment system

Tags: joomla, virtuemart, authorize.net

I have a virtuemart shop in joomla 2.5. I use the authorize.net payment system. My problem is I am not able to configure or add the thank you message after the buyer clicks on confirm purchase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are using VM2.x,

You can use common Joomla overrides for thank you message on VM.

The main Order confirmation message can be found at

```
components/com_virtuemart/views/cart/order_done.php
```

This page can be override using normal Joomla ways.

```
templates/your_template_folder/com_virtuemart/cart/order_done.php
```

Or you can just rewrite message using language files.

```
COM_VIRTUEMART_CART_ORDERDONE_THANK_YOU
```

found at `language/en-GB/en-GB.com_virtuemart.ini`

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

At least in Joomla3, VM3

This:

> components/com_virtuemart/views/cart/order_done.php

Should be:

> components/com_virtuemart/views/cart/tmpl/order_done.php

And this:

> templates/your_template_folder/com_virtuemart/cart/order_done.php

Should be:

> templates/your_template_folder/html/com_virtuemart/cart/order_done.php

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you can improve this ugly message yourself. Just find the order_done.php file, usually here in Virtuemart 3:

```
components/com_virtuemart/views/cart/tmpl/order_done.php
```

You can make it like this for example:

```
if ($this->display_title) {
    echo "<h3>".vmText::_('COM_VIRTUEMART_CART_ORDERDONE_THANK_YOU')."</h3>";
?>
    <div class="orderdone">
    <h4>This is what we are going to do next:</h4>
        <ul>
            <li>- You will receive a confirmation email.</li>
            <li>- We will check your order.</li>
            <li>- If neccessary, we will contact you for further information.</li>
            <li>- Blah blah blah...</li>
        </ul>
        <p>For any further questions, please contact us.</p>
        <p>Thanks again for your order!</p>
    </div>
<?php
}
echo $this->html;
$cuser = JFactory::getUser();
if(!$cuser->guest) echo shopFunctionsF::getLoginForm ();
```

Please notice the ?> closing tag before putting in some HTML, and after your HTML, start again with the PHP openingtag

Comment: It's probably better to make an override for this one in your template folder.